# Can Partial Order have just one element?

Tags: order-theory

I came across the question that asks
"Is it possible for a poset to have an element that is both maximum and minimum". So I can't imagine a element in poset being simultaneously be maximum and minimum, I guess poset must have element of 1.

If poset can have single elements then can Chain have one element as well? like if P = (X , <) is poset and X = {1,2,3,4,5} could I have chain of (1,1)?

Comment: Define "maximum" and "minimum." It is possible in posets to have maximal and minimal elements with more than one element, but not "maximum" and "minimum," in the usual definitions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The definition of "maximum" is the usual one: an element $\top$ with the property that $x \leq \top$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there exists a partially ordered set (poset) with one element. In fact, there is only one such thing.

There even exists a poset with *zero* elements!

You are correct that any poset that has an element which is both a maximum and a minimum must be the one element poset. There is a simple formal proof:

Let $*$ denote the element that is both maximal and minimal. Then for any element $x$ of the poset:

- $x \leq *$, because $*$ is a maximum
- $* \leq x$, because $*$ is a minimum

and by the antisymmetry law, this implies $x = *$.